# How can I stress-test my sever for the game Rust?

Tags: server, automated-testing

I am looking to stress test my server for the game Rust and monitor CPU, RAM and FPS. I could not find much around.

I general I think I will need a good amount of compute power, bunch of cloud based VM which generate the load through UDP using some headless client.

Monitoring CPU and RAM should be fairly easy, but how about the in game FPS?
Also I could not find much about Rust clients that could simulate a player.